# Not Receiving Push Notification in IOS 10.3.1 and Receiving twice in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios10.3

I am using Version 8.2.1. **The Issue is I am not getting notifications in IOS 10.3.1 but I am getting notifications in IOS 9(but twice)**.

Here is my code which I tried :

```
//In **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**   

    #define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) 
        if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
            {
                if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
                {
                    // iOS 8 Notifications
                    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

                    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
                center.delegate = self;
                [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) compl

    etionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
                 {
                     if( !error )
                     {
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
                         NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
                         NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                         NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
                     }  
                 }];  
            }

            if([self pushNotificationOnOrOff]) {
                NSLog(@"Push Notification is ON!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Push Notification is OFF.");
            }
            if (launchOptions != nil)
            {
                NSDictionary* dictionary1 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
                if (dictionary1 != nil)
                {
                    //RemoteNotification Payload
                    NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary1);
                    Globals.instance.isNotification = TRUE;
                    NSString* iUUID = [[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] objectForKey:@"UUID"];
                    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
                    NSDictionary* dictData = [Database getDataForUUID:iUUID];
                    if (dictData){
                        //Show dictData
                    }

                }
            }  

    **// Push Notification Receiving Methods**  

        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
                NSString* deviceTokenStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
                deviceTokenStr = [deviceTokenStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, deviceTokenStr.length-2)];
                if (!Globals.instance.deviceToken) {
                    Globals.instance.deviceToken = deviceTokenStr;
                }
        }
        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
                NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
        }

        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification {
                NSDictionary* data = [self checkForData:notification];
                if (data){
                    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) [self activeAlertForData: data];
                    else [self displayData: data];
                }
        }
        -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {

               NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
        }
        -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
                NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
        }
        -(BOOL)pushNotificationOnOrOff
        {
                BOOL pushEnabled=NO;
                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
                    pushEnabled=YES;
                } else {
                    pushEnabled=NO;
                }
                return pushEnabled;
        }
        - (NSDictionary*)checkForData:(NSDictionary*)notification {
                NSString* iUUID = [notification objectForKey:@"UUID"];
                NSDictionary* dict = [Database getUUID:iUUID];
                NSString* alertData = [notification objectForKey:@"alert"];

                return dict;
        }           
        - (void)activeAlertForData:(Inc*)inc {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Post”
                                                 message:inc.description
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                                actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                }];

                    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                                               actionWithTitle:@“Open”
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   // Jump to Post.
                                               }];
                    [alert addAction:yesButton];
                    [alert addAction:noButton];
                    UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
                    [vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                });
        }
```

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this as I am having the same issue with 10.3.1

Comment: no still it's pending. But I checked the error in didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError I think may be it's certificate error.

Comment: yes its was cert error for me. I had the automatically manage signing selected on xcode. Once I used the correct cert to sign the production version its all working correctly.

Comment: actually in my developer certificates push notification is not configured only in distribution certificates is configured.  anyway thanks ..